# Como pegar um elemento com as mesmas propriedades numa página?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Estou com dúvida de como pegar um elemento do tipo que se repete dentro da mesma página.
Tentei usar os seguintes XPath's que foram validados no FirePath, mas não tive sucesso quando rodei meu testes através do selenium.

```
   //div[@id='selectGenericMult']/child::div/child::input']

   (.//*[@id='selectGenericMult']/child::div/child::input)[last()]
```

Os dados da tag que estão tentando pegar são esses:

```
   <input class="ui-select-search input-xs ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Selecione" ng-disabled="$select.disabled" ng-hide="$select.disabled" ng-click="$select.activate()" ng-model="$select.search" role="combobox" aria-label="Select box" ondrop="return false;" style="width: 1331px;" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Não consegui adicionar a tag por completo.

Comment: A pergunta foi respondida na versão em inglês do stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593719/how-to-find-two-different-elements-but-with-same-information-using-xpath)